# How to compare (greater than, less than) times of day to an appointment time?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

**Solved Below**

I'm trying to create a chatbot that will automatically cancel an appointment being made if it's made outside of business hours. This is my current function:

```
(updated)
// This function checks for the availability of the time slot, which starts at 'dateTimeStart' and ends at 'dateTimeEnd'.
// 'dateTimeStart' and 'dateTimeEnd' are instances of a Date object.
function checkCalendarAvailablity (dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd) {
    var appsoftOpen = new Date();
    var appsoftClose = new Date();
    appsoftOpen.setHours(9);
    ppsoftClose.setHours(5);
    var time = dateTimeStart.getHours();
    var appsoftClose1 = appsoftClose.getHours();
    var appsoftOpen1 = appsoftOpen.getHours();
    time = Number(time);
    appsoftClose = Number(appsoftClose1);
    appsoftOpen = Number(appsoftOpen1);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    calendar.events.list({
      auth: serviceAccountAuth, // List events for time period
      calendarId: calendarId,
      timeMin: dateTimeStart.toISOString(),
      timeMax: dateTimeEnd.toISOString()
    }, (err, calendarResponse) => {
      // Check if there is an event already on the Calendar
      if (err || calendarResponse.data.items.length > 0) {
        reject(err || new Error('Requested time conflicts with another appointment'));
      } else if (err || time >= appsoftClose1) {
        reject(err || new Error('Requested time falls outside business hours'));
      } else if (err || time <= appsoftOpen1) {
        reject(err || new Error('Requested time falls outside business hours'));
          }else {
        resolve(calendarResponse);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Right now, it stops appointments from overlapping, but still lets an appointment be made at any time. Suggestions? Thanks!

**Solved**

```
// This function checks for the availability of the time slot, which starts at 'dateTimeStart' and ends at 'dateTimeEnd'.
// 'dateTimeStart' and 'dateTimeEnd' are instances of a Date object.
function checkCalendarAvailablity (dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd) {
    var time = dateTimeStart.getHours();
    // adjust for timezone
    time = time - 4;
    console.log(time);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    calendar.events.list({
      auth: serviceAccountAuth, // List events for time period
      calendarId: calendarId,
      timeMin: dateTimeStart.toISOString(),
      timeMax: dateTimeEnd.toISOString()
    }, (err, calendarResponse) => {
      // Check if there is an event already on the Calendar
      if (err || calendarResponse.data.items.length > 0) {
        reject(err || new Error('Requested time conflicts with another appointment'));
      } else if (err || time >= 17) {
        reject(err || new Error('Requested time falls outside business hours'));
      } else if (err || time <= 9) {
        reject(err || new Error('Requested time falls outside business hours'));
          }else {
        resolve(calendarResponse);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok there are a few things that needed to be changed like when you `setHours(9)` and assign the result to a variable where you want to `getHours()` later, it won't be anymore treated like a `Date`. Take a look at how I removed some things in the function (Number(time), Number(..)) and added with console.log() some examples on how you could compare dates by just using the operators `>`, `<`, `==`:

```
function checkCalendarAvailablity (dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd) {
    var appsoftOpen = new Date();
    var appsoftClose = new Date();
    appsoftOpen.setHours(9);
    appsoftClose.setHours(5);
    var time = dateTimeStart.getHours();
    appsoftClose = appsoftClose.getHours();
    appsoftOpen = appsoftOpen.getHours();

    // Comparison with operators >, <, ==
    console.log(time>appsoftOpen)
    console.log(time<appsoftOpen)
    console.log(time==appsoftOpen)

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    calendar.events.list({
      auth: serviceAccountAuth, // List events for time period
      calendarId: calendarId,
      timeMin: dateTimeStart.toISOString(),
      timeMax: dateTimeEnd.toISOString()
    }, (err, calendarResponse) => {
      // Check if there is an event already on the Calendar
      if (err || calendarResponse.data.items.length > 0) {
        reject(err || new Error('Requested time conflicts with another appointment'));
      } else if (err || time >= appsoftClose) {
        reject(err || new Error('Requested time falls outside business hours'));
      } else if (err || time <= appsoftOpen) {
        reject(err || new Error('Requested time falls outside business hours'));
      } else {
        resolve(calendarResponse);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aiming to keep it as a Date object, I just wanted to get the hour (either 9 or 17) as an integer, then just use that in a comparison. I tried your method first. I wasn't sure if I would be getting a string or an integer, so I wanted to make sure. Did you see where I've already done what you said in the else if loop? It's just not resolving as true

Comment: That is up to you, but in my answer I stated that this 
`appsoftOpen = appsoftOpen.setHours(9);` is not correct. You'd better do: `appsoftOpen.setHours(9);` and then you can retrieve them like this `var appsoftOpenHours = appsoftOpen.getHours();`

Comment: What exactly doesn't work for you? Can you also the current behavior and values (console.log(...)) and also your expected behavior? What are you passing to the function? Can you give an example?

Comment: I'm trying to create a chatbot that schedules an appointment upon request, but automatically cancels the appointment if it's being made outside of business hours (9am - 5pm). At the moment, it stops appointments from overlapping, but still allows appointments to be made before 9 and after 5. 
My goal was to create two Date objects for the open and close times, extract the hour from the three Date objects as an integer, then use comparisons to loop through error messages. 'dateTimeStart' is a Date object with the start time of the appointment and 'dateTimeEnd' is the same plus an hour.

Comment: I'm using dialogflow, so there's no real console beyond Firebase and I've been having trouble getting it to log anything since I started, else this all would be much easier.
And not really sure what you mean by "example", can you be more specific?

Comment: Nevermind, solved by using integers instead of date objects for simplicity. And yes, you get an integer when using Date .get methods, thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @MitchellAppsoft Nice you found out and you solved it! Post it as an answer clarifying the focus on the solution and how you managed to solve it. Also I would suggest to transform the time with the proper Date/Calendar methods to the right timezone instead of doing `-4` even if at this moment you might support only one timezone, just make it more scalable by not hardcoding a value like `4` in my opinion. Good job and keep it up!

Comment: How would that work? Would .getUTCHours work here? Or just using 21 and 13 as the open and close times?